# Find the conjugate function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My problem:** Suppose $f(x)=-\ln x + e^{x}$. Find the conjugate function of $f(x)$ 
**My attempt:** First, i have: $domf =(0;+\infty)$.
We have
$f^*(y)=\displaystyle \sup_{x \in (0;+\infty)} (xy+\ln x -e^{x})$. I set $g(x)=xy+lnx -e^{x}$. After that, I have $g'(x)=y+1/x+e^{-x}$. Now, I can't solve this equation to find root.
Thank you for reading my post. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You made a minor mistake finding the derivative:
$$g'(x)=y+\frac{1}{x}-e^x.$$
The roots of $g'$ cannot be obtained in a nice closed form. The best you can do is proving that $g'$ has only one root, so $g$ has a unique maximum there. To prove this, consider
$$g''(x)=-\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+e^x\right).$$